# Can i change the server url with sudzc?

Tags: ios, wsdl, sudzc

I am trying to generate source code from a `wsdl` file for `iOS`. I've stumbled upon a couple of tools and so far `wsclient++` and `sudz`c at least seem to work. But I need to send requests to different servers with the same `soap` interface, depending on the state of the `iOS` app.

In the source code generated by `wsclient` I can set the server URL via

```
MyWebService* ws = [MyWebService service];
// // set base url for entire application 
[SoapWebService setGlobalBaseUrl: @"http://domain.com"];
NSError* error = nil;
Result* rs = [ws callMethod: p1 param2:p2 error:&error];
```

Which would me allow me to do something like

```
if(condition1)  [SoapWebService setGlobalBaseUrl: @"http://betaserver.com"];
if(condition2)  [SoapWebService setGlobalBaseUrl: @"http://developserver.com"];
if(condition3)  [SoapWebService setGlobalBaseUrl: @"http://liveserver.com"];
```

Is there a way to archive something similar with the source code generated by `sudzc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the soap is the same response you shouldn't have a problem using your code.  There is a file that stores the server address.  The code generated by sudzc can be modified to any address.  I actually created a dynamic way of hitting servers.  I will find the file and code I used to do this.
You can search the project for your domain you used for sudzc.

I'm not in front of a mac right now, but I will update later.

```
UPDATE:
```

Ok, so I created a settings tab and allowed the user to input a specific ip address if necessary.  It saves the IP address in a dictionary and then this file retrieves it from the dictionary.  I left some of my original comments and added some in the code so you can see both ways. If it confuses you let me know and I'll edit again.  In my sudzc generated code I modified the file to this:

```
/*
wsUpdateQOH.m
The implementation classes and methods for the wsUpdateQOH web service.
Generated by SudzC.com
*/

#import "wsUpdateQOH.h"         
#import "Soap.h"
#import "Settings.h"
#define URL @"http://%@/webServiceAddress/updateqoh.asmx"




/* Implementation of the service */

@implementation wsUpdateQOH

- (id) init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        // take out hard coded address and add variable to  have a dynamic IP @"http://www.site.com/webServiceAddress/updateqoh.asmx"
        // here is the dictionary return and format of the url string
        NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"serverIP"];
        self.serviceUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:URL, savedValue];

        // uncomment for a hard coded address self.serviceUrl = @"http://%@/webServiceAddress/updateqoh.asmx";
        self.namespace = @"http://tempuri.org/webServiceAddress/UpdateQOH";
        self.headers = nil;
        self.logging = NO;

    }
    return self;

}

- (id) initWithUsername: (NSString*) username andPassword: (NSString*) password {
    if(self = [super initWithUsername:username andPassword:password]) {
    }
    return self;
}

+ (wsUpdateQOH*) service {
    return [wsUpdateQOH serviceWithUsername:nil andPassword:nil];
}

+ (wsUpdateQOH*) serviceWithUsername: (NSString*) username andPassword: (NSString*) password {
    return [[[wsUpdateQOH alloc] initWithUsername:username andPassword:password] autorelease];
}
// *** Below here is the soap actions ***
```

Comment: i would like to see your code, because EVERY generted function has something like SoapRequest* _request = [SoapRequest create: _target action: _action service: self soapAction: @"http://server.com/xyz/GetSecurityToken" postData: _envelope deserializeTo: @"NSString"]; which does not look as if i could set a global server url :/